# Finding a proper Book or a Internet Source on Combinational Logic

Tags: digital-logic

I am having trouble finding a book on Combinational Logic. For those who do not know what Combinational Logic is, that area of study talks about digital logic such as six logic gates(and, or, xor, not, etc) along with ALU, Multiplexer, full adders and half adders, k-map, controlled inverters(you get the idea).

I did run into many book entitled Computer Organization and Assembly Language at my college library but all the books already explain only the BASICS IDEAS of the topics (ie: truth values of logic gates, truth values of full adders which I already know)in the appendixes and does not intuitively explain how these things come together to create something useful.

The Class I am taking is Computer Organization and Assembly Language. It is not a Computer Architecture Class. I am surprised even the internet has a lack of resources in explaining how these things work and come together. I got an 82 on the first exam. However I feel incompetent on the topics covered after the first exam(which are the topics I mentioned before in this post.

The only internet source I could find is this one : http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_9/1.html But again it's not all that helpful because I already know what they are saying and did not learning anything new. Any links you have used when taking a similar class as mine when learning this material would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: "those who do not know what Combinational Logic is" are probably not interested in this question and in any case probably cannot answer it very well. :)

Comment: Well they might be interested in the topic at least since I explained what it was =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One of my favorite references](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135103827), even though my copy is a couple editions old. I would imagine you could find some older versions if you look around. Lots of practical information.

Comment: interesting, thank you for sharing this information!  =]

Answer (score 1):

While most books on logic design have just one chapter devoted to combinational logic, this book -- [Digital Logic Design: A Rigorous Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107027535) by Guy Even and Moti Medinahas -- has eight chapters in Part II: Combinational Circuits, covering almost 100 pages.  You can browse the table of contents on the Amazon page.  It is brand-new, having been published by Cambridge University Press on October 8, 2012.